# How could I spell out Pope Francis’s "Who am I to judge?" remark on gay priests?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

A [*New York Times* article from July 29, 2013](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/30/world/europe/pope-francis-gay-priests.html?hp&_r=0) introduced Pope Francis’s remark on gay priests which he made aboard the papal airplane on the way back from his first foreign trip, to Brazil.

> “If someone is gay and he searches for the Lord and has good will, **who
> am I to judge**?” Francis told reporters, speaking in Italian but using
> the English word “gay.”

Pope said this in Italian. Is "Who am I to judge?" a right translation? Couldn't it be "Whom am I to judge?" or "Who am I if I were to judge?" How could I spell out this phrase?

**P.S.** Ross Douthat provided full text of Pope’s remark including “Who am I to judge.” in [NYT Jul 30 issue](http://douthat.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/07/30/pope-francis-in-context/?hp&_r=0):

> “A gay person who is seeking God, who is of good will - well, **who am I
> to judge him**? The Catechism of the Catholic Church explains this very
> well. It says one must not marginalize these persons, they must be
> integrated into society. The problem isn’t this orientation — we must
> be like brothers and sisters. The problem is something else, the
> problem is lobbying either for this orientation or a political lobby
> or a Masonic lobby.”

I was under the impression that “Who am I to judge” was just a clip from a short Q&A between the pope and reporters aboard the papal plane, but it was a part of a well-structured discourse. It seems I made a premature post, without checking the full context of Pope’s message. Now the meaning is pretty clear to me.

Comment: He said "chi sono io per giudicare?" which means "who am I to judge?"

Comment: 1 - People really don't use 'whom' anymore. 2 - 'Whom am I ...' would be incorrect in the past anyway. 3 - "...remark on gay" -> "remark on homosexuality", because 'gay' is an adjective (mostly).

Comment: +1 @Mitch for "People really don't use 'whom' anymore"...  It sounds archaic/Old English-y

Comment: @Mitch - "Whom am I" wouldn't be old-fashioned, it would just be wrong. **Whom** is an *object* pronoun - the only context in which "Whom am I to judge?" would be if the answer were "Those people, over there."

Comment: @DJClayworth - He was, specifically, answering a question about gay priests and whether they should be disciplined. I certainly hope that his intention was to cover all gay people, but that wasn't what he was talking about right then.

Comment: Oops, sorry. That wasn't mentioned in the news reports I read.

Comment: @Mitch Maybe people like you don’t, but plenty of us do.

Comment: 'Plenty' is not 'most'. I'm just reporting the news, not judging it.

Comment: Whom am I to look down upon with great disdain for claiming that people don't really use "whom" any more?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Who am I to judge" is the correct translation.

It is not a question about judging someone else and asking who that might be (using *whom* as the object of *judge*): it is a question **about the asker himself — *Who am I?***

It means "What status do I have that allows me to judge?"

Comment: Yes, but perhaps add an explanation about predicate nominatives and subjective v. objective case?

Comment: @bib OK. *(And some more text in a comment)*

Comment: Excellent answer whit a perfect sentence at the end, +1.

Comment: Specifically, the subject is "I", and "who" is a pronoun used as a predicate nominative.  These are terms used with a linking verb, and the predicate is basically equated to the subject and takes the same case as the subject. "Who" is the subjective case, as opposed to "whom" which is the objective case. If the pronoun were used as a true object,   (such as "Whom did you hit?", it would take the objective case.

Comment: It should also be noted that "Who am I to judge?" is [not an uncommon phrase in English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Who+am+I+to+judge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).